# How to get address by password or something else using web3j?

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I'm using web3j for Java. I able to create new accounts for my ethereum but i don't understand how i can get the single address using password or something else.

Answer (score 1):

`Credentials credentials = Credentials.create("password");`

Will allow you to access `credentials.getAddress()`